# Pass value dynamically to Cordova - Onsen - AngularJS - Share button

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

Creating am iOS Cordova app, with Onsen UI and AngularJS. I have a tool bar with "share button" on right side.

The content on the page is loaded dynamically and I need to share particular text on the page.

```
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
      <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Details</div>
    <div class="right">
            <ons-toolbar-button>
              <ons-icon icon="ion-share" fixed-width="false" style="vertical-align: -4px;" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('{{DynamicText}}', null, null, 'http://www.sample.com')"></ons-icon>
            </ons-toolbar-button>
          </div>
  </ons-toolbar>
```

The value for `{{DynamicText}}` is not loading. When I share the text,  `{{DynamicText}}` is just printed and not the value of it.

Similarly tried on a button, this works.

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message and link', null, null, 'http://www.sample.com')">message and link</button>
```

Passing dynamic value, did not work.

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('{{DynamicText}}', null, null, 'http://www.sample.com')">message and link</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DynamicText` is a variable on the scope so:

Change `onclick` to `ng-click`

Use `DynamicText` as the variable:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share(DynamicText, null, null, 'http://www.sample.com')
```

Full code:

```
<button ng-click="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(DynamicText, null, null, 'http://www.sample.com')">message and link</button>
```

Comment: When I use the "ng-click" the "Share action sheet" on IOS device does not appear. So clicking on it nothing happens.